# How productive and necessary is the use of ORM in Android

Tags: android, orm, ormlite, greendao

I was wondering about the ***real neccessity of using an ORM on android***. What are the "**Pluses**" that ,using an ORM when conding on android, can we get?
Isn't using the **native android approach sufficiant** (Using SqlLIte and writing your own classes and own sql queries(***which i think takes lot of time and code lines***))?

What are the benefits and disadvantages of using an ORM especially on mobile devices?

Comment: Android doesn't not support relational DB. And ORM helps you to design relational DB into Android.

Comment: But you can still interact with DB without an ORM, using SQLite and writing your own classes ans your own sql queries.

Comment: Yes you can. ORMs also do the same thing. They provides some utility classes for you, but internally they do the same thing. The purpose is to use ORM, if you have to maintain relational DB it would be much easier than default one.

Comment: @PankajKumar : i don't think that there is an application that needs lots of tables an hense be complex to maintain , do you see my point ?

Comment: You are right.. But it doesn't mean that all application have 2 or 3 tables. They can have more tables and if you used relational db into Android you will realize that how it hard to maintain (But not impossible without use of ORM tools)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ORM helps you work on and think about your code more on the level of Object and less  about tables and columns. This is important if you want to maintain Object Orientation of your code. ORM helps translate table/columns space to and from your Objects so you don't have to or at least very minimally.

ORM does not have to be complex and costly. There are now a lot of simple library/framework if your need is simple. I use [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) for my Android projects so far.

Comment: Hi @Hafiz, can you describe me how the ORM could be useful in a mobile application, because i don't think that there is an application that needs lots of tables an hense be complex, do you see my point ?

Comment: Hi @ProXamer, ORM usefulness is quite the same whether in mobile or in other space (desktop, web). The data could be small and simpler in mobile case but the need to translate between Object-Property and Table-Column is the same. You could save time from writing and maintaining code that translate between tables and objects.

Comment: Agree with Hafiz, It takes a lot of the minutia away from your application, however, just like with an abstraction, it can be more difficult to track down issues. I've been using ActiveAndroid (http://www.activeandroid.com/) for my latest Android application.

Answer (score 4):

Using an ORM-framework gets you the same advantages and disadvantages as using a well tested,(professional)  library does:

- less code you have to write and maintain
- librarycode is less error prone
- librarycode is more likely to be optimized
- the library is maintained by someone else
- your apk probably gets a little bit bigger, since the library will provide more functionality than you actually need

Additionally using an ORM helps you to concentrate on your business logic, since you don't have to switch from OO-thinking to relational-db-thinking and back again.

A disadvantage I can think of is that if you have some very complex queries writing the queries yourself might be more performant, since (depending on the ORM) you can write one single query where the ORM will use multiple queries (lazy loading). But ORM-frameworks I know also provide the ability to write customized queries.

From my experience I can tell:
I developed an app with about 50 tables to hold data needed for nearly everything. My queries were pretty complex (several joins).

Using an ORM (greendao) saved me weeks due to less code that had to be written and to be debugged.
Also the fact that I could concentrate on my problems and didn't have to care about the underlying tablestructure saved me some time.

Besides: My own development speed is much higher in java than in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

**Why ORMLite ?**

- ORMLite is commonly used for Java applications and supports many    different types of underlying relational database implementations .
- Mobile application development is becoming more and more important    for software solutions and ORMLite has released a new and more    reliable Android supported version of their API.

  - Until looking into ORMLite,support for more advanced database uses in Android apps was    sparse.
- Learning to use ORMLite with mobile application development    will help make better mobile applications that can be more easily  maintained and created .
- ORMLite in Android shows how an object oriented language based application can benefit from using    ORDM(Object Relational Database Mapping) technology .

  - With out the technology there is a bottleneck at the data transfer point – all of    your class structures and OO designs need to be flattened and    simplified back to a construct that (in the case of SQLite) may only have 5 data types!!
  - There is an elegant solution to the data storage problem that complements the designing and analysis that is  involved in using OO, and ORMLite is a “lite” way to start learning    about it .

**Advantages:**

- Allows developers to convert data from rich data types used   in
     object oriented programming languages to lower level   relational
     database types.
- Allows the use of self defined abstract data types
     (ADTs) in database storage .
- Decreases the amount of code in
     applications because they    don’t need to generate SQL statements
- For example instead of storing “address” as a VARCHAR, you    can
     store it as an ADT Address with the specified format of that data
     type. Have all applications use the same Address class and 
  continuity is achieved.

**Disadvantages:**

- Poor performance and scalability compared to other data  storage methods. With the ability to have complex ADTs, efficiency may be lower for large scale applications .
- Database size can also increase depending on the amount of  methods stored with the objects and the number of entries  stored.
- Many larger applications with frequent database read/write  activity will not gain from ORDM.

For more details Check [HERE](http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474455802/ormlite-for-android) and [HERE](http://www.morgan-design.com/2011/07/ormlite-android-and-sqlite-good.html)

Comment: It's not about ORMLite but ORM in general. Greendao for example doesn't have some of the disadvantages.